# Is using DATE in SELECT query on a DATETIME indexed column in mysql correct with respect to optimization?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a very huge table (425+ million rows).

```
CREATE TABLE `DummyTab` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  `BeginDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  ......
  ......
  KEY `BeginDate_index` (`dBegDate`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Selects are done based on "BeginDate" and other criteria on this table

```
select * from DummyTab where Name like "%dummyname%" and BeginDate>= 20141101
```

Now in this case only the date field is being provided out of datetime (although it'll be used as 2014-11-01 00:00:00).

**Question is DOES THE OPTIMIZER MAKE USE OF DATETIME INDEX PROPERLY EVEN WHEN JUST DATE IS PROVIDED IN THIS CASE ? or should the index be set on a "date" field to be used more effectively rather than a "datetime"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `BeginDate_index` can still be used when the query is specified with a DATE-only filter (also applying additional criteria on `Name` won't disqualify the index either).

If you look at [this SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66ee0/3) of random data, and expand the `Execution plan` at the bottom, you'll see something like:

```
ID   SELECT_TYPE  TABLE  TYPE     POSSIBLE_KEYS    KEY             KEY_LEN   REF    ROWS   FILTERED                EXTRA
1    SIMPLE       DummyTab range  BeginDate_index  BeginDate_index 6         17190  100    Using index condition;  Using where
```

(Specifically `KEY` is `BeginDate_index`).
Note however that use of the index is not guaranteed, e.g. if you execute the same query against a wider range of date criteria, that a different plan may be used (e.g. if you run the same fiddle for `> 20140101`,  the `BeginDate_index` is no longer used, since it does not offer [sufficient selectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimization)).

**Edit, Re: Comment on Exactness**
Since `BeginDate` is a datetime, the literal `20141101` will be also be converted to a Datetime (once). From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html):

> If one of the arguments is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column and the other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp before the comparison is performed.

So again, yes, as per your last paragraph, the literal in the filter `BeginDate >= 20141101` will be converted to the exact date time `20141101000000` (`2014-11-01 00:00:00`) and any eligible indexes will be *considered* (but again, never guaranteed).

A common issue where indexes cannot be used is because the filter predicates are *NOT [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)* is when a function is applied to a column in a filter, as the engine would need to evaluate the function on all remaining rows in the query. Some [examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799616/314291).

So altering your example a bit, the below queries do the same thing, but the second one is much slower. This query is sargable:

```
SELECT * FROM DummyTab
WHERE BeginDate < 20140101;  -- Good
```

Whereas this is NOT:

```
SELECT * FROM DummyTab
WHERE YEAR(BeginDate) < 2014; -- Bad
```

[Updated SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66ee0/2) - again, look at the `Execution Plans` at the bottom to see the difference.

Comment: so is the index calculated for DATETIME = 20141101 same/similar as DATETIME - 20141101 12:12:59, or mysql figures it out that this is a close one ? Is the exactness of the 'time' from given DATETIME immaterial when using indexes?